# Действие на комбинацию клавиш WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сделать зум panel по зажатой комбинации...*Как отследить комбинацию клавиш Ctrl + MouseWheel?* Не понимаю, как одновременно работать с событием вращения колесика мыши и нажатием Ctrl. Вот что есть на данный момент:

```
private void MainForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
         if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control) & колесо мыши активно)
         {
            //####работает для MouseWheel####
            //if (e.Delta > 0) //zoom +
            //{
            //    canvas.Width += e.Delta / 5;
            //    canvas.Height += e.Delta / 5;
            //    canvas.Location = new Point(canvas.Location.X - e.Delta / 10, canvas.Location.Y - e.Delta / 10);
            //}
            //else if (e.Delta < 0) //zoom -
            //{
            //    canvas.Width += e.Delta / 5;
            //    canvas.Height += e.Delta / 5;
            //    canvas.Location = new Point(canvas.Location.X - e.Delta / 10, canvas.Location.Y - e.Delta / 10);
            //}
        }
}
```

Спасибо

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828121/shift-mouse-wheel-horizontal-scrolling Гуглите на английском пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Оно работает О_о

```
private void this_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0) //zoom +
            {
                canvas.Width += e.Delta / 5;
                canvas.Height += e.Delta / 5;
                canvas.Location = new Point(canvas.Location.X - e.Delta / 10, canvas.Location.Y - e.Delta / 10);
            }
            else if (e.Delta < 0) //zoom -
            {
                canvas.Width += e.Delta / 5;
                canvas.Height += e.Delta / 5;
                canvas.Location = new Point(canvas.Location.X - e.Delta / 10, canvas.Location.Y - e.Delta / 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Учтите, что такой способ сравнения не будет работать, если одновременно с `Control` зажать `Alt` и/или `Shift`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну так мне и надо то только с ctrl, вы ж когда меняете зум, зажимаете ctrl + '+' например)